# Printing \ref as a letter

Tags: cross-referencing

When using `\label` and `\ref`, can I get the `\ref` to display as a letter instead of a number (so if `\ref` is `3`, it will print `c` instead)?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want: if the item to which you are referring is numbered 3, then the reference should show that number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default counter representation is `\arabic` (or numerical). If you want a counter to be referenced alphabetically rather than numberically, then you can redefine the representation using

```
\newcounter{mycount}
\renewcommand{\themycount}{\alph{mycount}}
```

`\the<counter>` refers to the representation of the counter. So you're essentially redefining it from being displayed as `\arabic` to `\alph`.

---

If you don't care about what is displayed and how it's referenced, then the following will work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\section{This is a section}\label{ref:section}
This is section~\ref{ref:section}. This is section~\aaalphnum{\ref{ref:section}}.
\end{document}
```

The [`fmtcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) can easily be used to convert between different number formats.

Comment: I was wondering if there were a way to do this other than to counter names.

Answer (score 2):

Any counter can be printed alphabetically using the command `\alph{counter}`.  You can make that work with `\label` and `\ref` by redefining the counter you are referencing to print things that way.  For example, to refer to sections by letter, write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\thesection{\alph{section}}
\begin{document}
 \section{A section}
 \label{s:a section}

 In section \ref{s:a section}\dots
\end{document}
```

Of course, all your sections will be "lettered" rather than numbered; however, it is very confusing to refer to a numbered item by letter, so this is probably what you should do anyway if you want references to print letters.